# Round Rect Button connecting to ViewController.h

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So, this is kind of hard for me to explain, but i will do my best. I am most likely making a simple mistake, but i cant figure it out. So, im on my mainstoryboard, with a round rect button on the controller. I open the dual view editor and open up the viewcontroller.h file. Now, i should be able to press control and drag the button connection in the .h file, but i cant. It wont give the option to. Does that make sense?

Any ideas?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62Xfn5oAjw0
Edit: For example, i need to do the part at 3:08, but it won't allow me to do that.

Edit 2: Ok. So, i put the button on a single view controller, and everything worked the way it should. BUT, when i put the same button on a tab bar view controller, it doesn't play the sound it should when pressed. The sound played when it wasnt on the tab bar controller just fine though.

Comment: show the code for initializing the UIButton

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: I watched the video and I know what you're doing. You're trying to create an outlet. When you right click the button there'll be a circle that says  "New referencing outlet". Try dragging that circle to the viewcontroller. Otherwise, just type what comes up after he does that manually. Easy.**

It should already be connected automatically. You never actually drag the button to the view controller. The view should already be connected and therefore any part of the view is connected. However, if you're having problems in the future, try this to sort of start over.

What you're going to want to do is go up to file>New File

Then you're going to want to select a new view controller, and make sure you tick the box that says "Include a XIB" or something similar.

After that, it will make all the connections you need. Any part of the view will automatically connect to the view controller, and all you'll need to do is create the IB actions to preform things in the interface and connect them to buttons when you're ready.

Comment: That worked with a single view controller, but not the tab bar. Any idea?

Comment: Could you re-word that please? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: EDIT: I think what you need to do is set the delegate. Right click on the tab bar and drag the "delegate" circle over to "File's Owner". Please give me the answer mark if this works, otherwise I'm happy to help you if it doesn't. Again, I didn't understand your question completely and so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the viewcontroller as the file owner of the view. This is done in the story board.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you'd want to ctrl+drag the button to your ViewController.h . If you wanted to link the button to a ViewController in the storyboard, then you just ctrl+drag it to that ViewController. I may not have understood your question, but I think this is what you want.